# Is it possible to add a field/button to a pdf that allows a user to insert an image using Reader?

Tags: pdf, images, adobe-acrobat

A client of mine wants to be able to edit text and add images to a PDF. I've set the text fields but struggling with adding images. I've created a button that runs JavaScript to add a PDF but can this be changed to add JPEGs.

Is anyone any else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is currently anyway to add an image into a PDF using Adobe Reader.

I have only read about being able to do this in Acrobat, LiveCycle or another Photo editing program.